# Selecting DataRows with valuetype DateTime based on only year

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I need to select a 'DateTime' field from my DataSet based on only the year. (To begin with, may expand to year + month later)

The program exits with an error when it is run, and I'm unsure what the real query would be in this case. - I do NOT have access to the database to do it in the query, so it has to be in the DataSet

```cs
IEnumerable<DataRow> selectedRows = myLicenseInfoDataSet.Tables[0].Select("CreationDate = #" + startDateTime.Year.ToString() + "#");
```

Comment: so test if the date is between >= 1/1/year, and <=31/12/year

Comment: @BugFinder Yeah, that makes sense. Guess my brain is afk today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my issue by doing the following:

```cs
                ICollection<DataRow> selectedRows = myLicenseInfoDataSet.Tables[0].Select("CreationDate >= #" + startDateTime + "# AND CreationDate <= #" + startDateTime.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1) + "#");
```